# Why ping localhost from root IPv6 selected?

Tags: networking, dns

Linux zika.gattaca.net 5.8.0-48-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 19 14:25:20 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I just noticed that only when I ping from the root IPv6 is selected:

root@#########:/etc/samba# ping localhost

```
PING localhost(localhost (::1)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from localhost (::1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.226 ms
64 bytes from localhost (::1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.204 ms
64 bytes from localhost (::1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.177 ms
64 bytes from localhost (::1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.187 ms
64 bytes from localhost (::1): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.142 ms
64 bytes from localhost (::1): icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.142 ms
64 bytes from localhost (::1): icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.213 ms
^C
--- localhost ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 137ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.142/0.184/0.226/0.033 ms
```

brad@#########:~$ ping localhost

```
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.194 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.131 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.130 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.133 ms
^C
--- localhost ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 80ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.130/0.147/0.194/0.027 ms
```

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

if I ping 127.0.0.1 IPv4 is used, OK
if I ping ::1 IPv6 is used, OK

It looks like the name resolution is not working from user but from root only.

Comment: I dont see any error. Use ping for IPv4 and ping6 for IPv6 and tell us the result.

Comment: the issue is that I have other apps which use IPv4, not because I wanted to resolve localhost name by IPv4 and not IPv6. This issue was found out when I tried to troubleshot other things.

Comment: What are these other things?

Comment: will be another topic for 'other things' let's focus on this topic for now please